# Setting a default starting file for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, processing, libraries

I am learning to use a programming language based on Java called Processing that's basically a library. While it comes with it's own IDE, I find too minimal and basic, so I wish to use Eclipse instead. 
While I have been able to get it to work, it's a whole lot of hassle to import the library everytime I start a new project, and I was wondering if it's possible to set some sort of default starting "skeleton" for Eclipse where everything is already loaded and ready to go.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

While you can create an eclipse template, it's worth trying the [Proclipsing Processing plugin](https://github.com/ybakos/proclipsing).

On top of creating Processing projects it makes it easy to manage/import Processing libraries and (hopefully still) generate applications.